# gitignore file does not actually exist

Tags: git

I created a global git ignore file using [**this method**](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore):

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

When I check where the file is it tells me the file is here

```
$ git config --global core.excludesfile
c:/Users/username/.gitignore_global
```

But when I check the directory there is no git ignore file.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should add the file by hand first.

Comment: I cannot create a file named `.gitignore_global` in windows 7. `You must type a file name`

Comment: Then name it as `global.gitignore`

Comment: So I created the file, but windows thinks it's a text document instead of a `gitignore` file, even though there is no `txt` extension

Comment: Git will find & read the ignore file according to git configurations. You don't need care what windows could do.

Comment: @EricWang In that case git is still not using that file. I have 3 lines in my `gitignore` file. git is ignoring my ignore file, kinda

Comment: I just did a test, it works on linux, no matter the project itself contain a `.gitignore` file or not.

Comment: *"When I check where the file is it tells me the file is here"* -- Git doesn't tell you that it found the file. It just tells you that it is configured to use that file as global ignore file. It's up to you to create the file and write the right stuff in it.

Comment: Furthermore you can files with leading dots in windows. Instead of trying to name the file `.gitignore_global` name it `.gitignore_global.` (the trailing dot is important), windows will remove the trailing dot and your file will be named as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You must create this file.

However, Windows Explorer can sometimes be picky about file and folder names, particularly when they start with a .

Fortunately, the command prompt isn't as picky.  Navigating to your user's home directory (C:/Users/[username]/) and running the command
   `echo "" > .gitignore_global`

will create the file.  You can then use Notepad, Notepad++, Sublime Text or whatever to edit the file.

Likewise, `mkdir .DOT` will bypass Window Explorer's restriction on folder names as well.

Comment: As I already explained in a comment on the question. It's possible to create files with leading dots in windows. Instead of trying to name the file .gitignore_global name it .gitignore_global. (the trailing dot is important), windows will remove the trailing dot and your file will be named as desired.

Comment: I created the file, added the line `*.tmp` yet untracked `.tmp` files are still showing up in git status.

Comment: @Vader, is it possible the .tmp files were already added to the index?  That is, were they added in a previous commit accidentally?  If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: @KevinL no git tell me they are untracked.

Comment: @KevinL now when I get weird thing happening in git.

`$ git config --global core.excludesfile`  `C:UsersUSERNAMEglobal.gitignore`

Comment: Did you try rerunning `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`?

Answer (score 1):

the command `git config --global core.excludesfile <PATH>` sets the path of your global ignore file. Git will not created this file for you. You need to create it yourself under the path you specified.